# Hartshorne Chapter IV Exercise1.8 (c): How to prove $\delta_P$ depends only on the analytic isomorphism class of $\mathcal O_{X,P}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The background of the exercise goes as follows:

> 1.8. Let $X$ be an integral projective scheme of dimension 1 over $k$, and let $\tilde{X}$ be its normalization (II, Ex. 3.8). Then there is an exact sequence of sheaves on $X$,
> $$
> 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow f_{*} \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}} \rightarrow \sum_{P \in X} \tilde{\mathcal{O}}_{P} / \mathcal{O}_{P} \rightarrow 0
> $$
> where $\tilde{\mathcal{O}}_{P}$ is the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_{P}$. For each $P \in X$, let $\delta_{P}=\operatorname{length}\left(\tilde{\mathcal{O}}_{P} / \mathcal{O}_{P}\right)$.

Now part (c) says we can prove $\delta_P$ depends only on the analytic isomorphism class of $\mathcal O_{X,P}$, but how? Maybe we should consider something like $m_P^n/m_P^{n+1}$? I have no idea. Could you provide some help? Thanks.

Comment: I think the main points are that 1) you can compute lengths after passing to the residue field at $P$, and 2) you can compute residue fields after passing to the completion. There could be a more straightforward approach, but any time I can get my hands on a vector space I'm happier.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for answering. I know these ideas, but still don't know how to handle it. Could you write a more concrete proof outline?